# Where can wsconsume of JBossWS be found after installing JBoss on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wsdl, jboss-tools

I have installed JBoss on Eclipse from Eclipse marketplace.  The following snapshot shows the result of the installation:
[image]

There is not a wizard for wsconsume.  As my understanding, it is a command line tool only.  Where can I find wsconsume?

Actually I am only interested in using wsconsume. All the installations are solely for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have installed `JBoss Tools for Eclipse`. As its name suggests it's only tooling around JBoss related technologies (with `JBoss Application Server` being one of the most important among them).
`JBossWS` and its `wsconsume` companion tool is distributed with `JBoss Application Server` (JBossAS for short) which is separate standalone product. Please download it from [JBoss download site](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads). Current community version is 7.1.1.
Next, unzip archive to some folder (I'll refer to it as JBOSS_HOME from now on).
Wsconsume tool is placed in `JBOSS_HOME/bin` folder as scripts for Windows and Unix/Linux systems: `wsconsume.bat` and `wsconsume.sh` respectively.

As an alternative you could download only [JBossWS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/downloads) itself instead of entire JBossAS, but for some reasons I find it easier the way I described above.

I don't know if `JBoss Tools for Eclipse` helps with `wsconsume` in any manner. I always use it from command line and I'm quite satisfied with it.

(I don't know your current experience with JBoss technologies so please excuse me if my explanations are too basic.)

Comment: thanks a lot.  My experience with JBoss is zero.  I just want to use wsconsume to generate java code from wsdl files.